# AccountQuery does not give bank account number and routing number in QuickBooks

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

When I am running AccountQuery and parsing AccountRet , I can see there is a field bank_number but it does not give me the bank account number of the account .....Also I cant seem to find any field for Routing number ...

I am trying to fetch these only when AccountType is 'Bank'

Can anyone help please ?